# Grizzly PUT request with json body fails

Tags: java, http, server, jersey, grizzly

I have the java server on the cloud running. Everything is ok with GET and DELETE requests, but not ok with the PUT request. I have the following PUT request handler

```
@PUT
@JSONP(queryParam = "callback")
public void putEvent(String eventJson) throws Exception {
    Event event = new ObjectMapper().readValue(eventJson, Event.class);
    EventDao.getInstance().saveOrUpdateEvent(event);
}
```

And here is the Server class

```
public static final String BASE_API_URI = "http://localhost:8080/myrest-api/";

public boolean getFileCacheEnabled() {
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server();
    final HttpServer httpServer = server.startServer();
    System.out.println("Press enter to stop the server...");
    System.in.read();
    httpServer.shutdown();
}

public HttpServer startServer() {
    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.myrest.events");
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_API_URI), rc);
    server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(getHttpHandler(), "/page");
    return server;
}

public HttpHandler getHttpHandler() {
    StaticHttpHandler handler = new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/resources/webapp/");
    handler.setFileCacheEnabled(getFileCacheEnabled());
    return handler;
}
```

When I send PUT request with following JSON body

```
{
    "name":"SimpleName",
    "description":"SimpleDescription",
    "author":"Me"
}
```

I get

```
Status: 500 Request failed
```

Although when I deploy the app locally, and try the same everything is fine. Btw I tried POST request instead, I get the same error.

Comment: You realize that JSON and JSONP are two different things?

Comment: Yes, but I just don't get why when I run my web app locally and send the same PUT request with JSON body using Postman it works, but when I deploy and run it in the cloud and send the same request from Postman - it doesn't.